# dplyr 0.7.7 binary for R 3.3.3

Tags: r, dplyr, install.packages

I  need to install version >= 0.7.7 in R 3.3.3 (cannot upgrade). Is this possible?  I tried:

```
install.packages("C:/Bla/dplyr_0.7.7.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

but get:

```
non-zero exit status
```

Is there a binary for windows? Thanks!

Comment: Try `devtools::install_version("dplyr", "0.7.7")`.

Comment: thanks. I think the issue is that it takes from mcran: https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-05-01/

Comment: What is the close vote for please ?!

Comment: this appears to do the trick: install.packages('dplyr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')